# Namespace Meteor methods to package

Tags: javascript, methods, meteor, namespaces

I'm writing a package that exposes a few Meteor.methods. Is there a smarter way to namespace them to the package than hardcoding their names like this?

```
Meteor.methods({
  'my:package/methodName': function ...
})
```

A way to figure out the name of a package from inside its JavaScript files would be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

That is generally how we namespace things today with Meteor.methods.

If you wanted to do something dynamically, you could do something like this:

```
var namespace = "my:package";
var myFunc = function() {/* Meteor Method Function Here */}

var meteorMethods = {};
meteorMethods[namespace + "uniqueFuncName"] = myFunc;
Meteor.methods(meteorMethods);
```

It isn't too pretty and you still need a way to get the package name... if you don't 'var' the namespace variable (in this example) it would be available throughout your package.